# breakpoint works and other works not equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

I have two identical codes, each bringing a text by Json.

First problem: NSNotificationCenter, viewDidLoad - among others is discolored in one of the codes and the other is with color, this is a mistake?

Second problem: What is discolored seems that no calls this method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:selector (startDownloadContent:) name: @ "startDownloadContent" object: nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:selector (defineContent:) name: @ "defineContent" object: nil];
```

while the the other view call (I put a breakpoint where flame)

Comment: Discolored? Sorry to be blunt but what are you talking about? That doesn't make sense. Maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: If you're saying it's not syntax highlighted in some places I'd try cleaning your project (cmd + shift +k). It won't hurt anything to not be colored properly.

Comment: Also: "I put a breakpoint where flame". What? Is flame a typo?

Comment: sorry for my bad English. two class similar, but the colors are different methods. link has image upload -> http://postimg.org/image/fuepuhki7/

Comment: Ah ok. I understand now. I kind of thought that's what you meant, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

The lighter blue breakpoints are disabled. You can click them to re-enable them. This allows you turn breakpoints on and off on the fly without deleting them.

Comment: Yes I know. The problem is that this line does not work
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startDownloadContent: ) name:@"startDownloadContent" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defineContent: ) name:@"defineContent" object:nil];

Comment: Your code should pause when you hit that breakpoint. There's a button to step through it that looks like a fast forward arrow.

Comment: that means something different color?

Comment: he's not doing this pause, even it there

Comment: If it's not pausing then that line of code isn't being called. Add a log statement to verify it's getting called. It isn't though since it's not triggering the breakpoint. Dark blue = breakpoint on. Light blue = breakpoint off.

Comment: Can you explain what your issue is again? I don't get what isn't working.